# Language choice affects text overflow in html(bootstrap) (Django)

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap` to implement my post detail page.

It works well and fit perfectly into tho format when using Korean.
[image]

But, if I wrote english contents, it overflow the format.
[image]

What's wrong with it? 
Here is the code :

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings


def upload_location(instance, file_name):
    return "{}/{}".format(instance.author.username, file_name)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, blank=True, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "posts:detail",
            kwargs={
                "pk": self.id,
            }
        )

    def get_image_url(self):
        if self.image:
            return self.image.url
        return "http://placehold.it/300x200"
```

`post_detail.html`

```
{% extends 'chacha_dabang/skeleton/base.html' %}
{% load pipeline %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <section class="post-content-section">
            <h2> {{ post.title }} </h2>
            <h5 style="text-align: right;"> {{ post.created_at }} </h5>
            <hr class="thin">
            <img src="{{ post.get_image_url }}" alt="image">
            <p> {{ post.content }} </p>
        </section>

        </br>
        <hr class="thin">
        </br>

        <section id="comment-section" data-post-id={{ post.pk }}>
            <h3> 댓 글 (<span id="comment-count"></span>)</h3>
            <ul>
            </ul>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}
    {% javascript "comments" %}
    {% javascript "message" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please provide code. As is, it's very hard to determine what may be wrong without seeing the code that's causing this.

Comment: @Karin Sorry, I edit it!

Comment: Is there CSS that goes with this? I actually think we just need the HTML and CSS - the Python shouldn't be necessary :)

Comment: If you put a giant string of characters without spaces, then it will overflow because the browser will only wrap the text when it encouters a space. Normal english words aren't that long... so maybe try it with a more realistic example ;-).

Comment: @solarissmoke Cool. It works when I type realistic examples :)

Comment: @solarissmoke I want to truncate the title when it reach the end of title section, which means I don't want to set certain specific length for truncate. Any idea ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean...